# Jquery | Variable value working as a string instead of calling another variable

Tags: jquery, string, variables

The Html:

```
<div id="div1" name="divname">Something</div>
<div id="div2" name="divname">Something else</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

The Jquery:

```
$('[name="divname"]').click( function (){ 

   var divnum = $(this).attr('id'); 
   var divout = 'out' + divnum;

   var outdiv1 = 'first div clicked';
   var outdiv2 = 'second div clicked';

   $('#output').html(divout);

});
```

Desired Result after div1 got clicked:

```
<div id="output">first div clicked</div>
```

Actual Result:

```
<div id="output">outdiv1</div>
```

Help Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
$('[name="divname"]').click( function (){ 

  var divnum = $(this).attr('id'); 
  var out={div1:'first div clicked',div2:'second div clicked'}
  $('#output').html(out[divnum]);

});
```

That's because if you say...

```
var divout = 'out' + divnum;
```

... `divout` is a string.

But you want to access the variable whose name is the string which `divout` contains.
So the easiest way is creating an object, because you can access its properties like this:

1. obj.property
2. obj['property']

So

- If you know the name of the property:

  `obj.property` or `obj['property']`
- If you don't know its name but you have a variable `myvar` which contains it:

  `obj[myvar]` (`myvar = 'property'`)

**EDIT**: 
Anyway, in that case I would use that:

```
$('[name="divname"]').click( function (){ 

  var divnum = $(this).attr('id'); 
  $('#output').html((divnum=='div1'?'first':'second')+' div clicked');

});
```

It checks if `divnum` is `'div1'` and, if yes, the result is `'first div clicked'`. If not, `'second div clicked'`.

This way you don't need any objects, only a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get anywhere good naming variables like that. If your variables have very similar names (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ...), you should either be using an object or an array to store them.

In this case, try using objects to create a mapping between names and values:

```
var outdivs = {
  'div1': 'first div clicked',
  'div2': 'second div clicked'
};

$('[name="divname"]').click(function() {
   var divnum = $(this).attr('id');

   $('#output').text(outdivs[divnum]);
});
```

Comment: If you use `var divnum = 'out' + $(this).attr('id');`, then `divnum` will be `'outdiv1'` or `'outdiv2'`. But `outdivs['outdiv1']` and `outdivs['outdiv2']` don't exist.